# Build failed. See the build log for details after it was updated newest version xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

> Build failed. No compatible framework found for assembly '/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/MSBuild/4.0/MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.exe' (required framework: .NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
>
> Build: 1 error, 0 warnings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just restart Xamarin.Studio to reload the license information. See more information [over here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/66875/build-failed-see-the-build-log-for-details-after-it-was-updated-newest-version-xamarin).

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm gathering, this has something to do with Xamarin's installer not properly installing Mono. I uninstalled Xamarin Studio completely and reinstalled it - that seems to have fixed it.